# why is clear $\frac{FD}{DI}\cdot \frac{CI}{CF}=2$? with ELMO 2014 Shortlist problem 12

Tags: geometry

**Question:**

> Let $AB=AC$ in $\triangle ABC$, and let $D$ be a point on segment $AB$. The tangent at $D$ to the circumcircle $\omega$ of $BCD$ hits $AC$ at $E$. The other tangent from $E$ to $\omega$ touches it at $F$, and $G=BF \cap CD$, $H=AG \cap BC$.
>
> Let  $I$ be the second point of intersection of  $\omega$  and $AC$,
>
> show that
>
> $$\dfrac{FD}{DI}\cdot \dfrac{CI}{CF}=2$$

[image]

This problem is from this ELMO 2014 Shortlist G12,and  see  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=3557466&sid=3d30a3907f3709aca1d9867e2c7d080e#p3557466

why this reslut is clear?

I have consider sometime,and don't understand why is clear? someone can prove it?

Thank you